# Adding functions to jquery custom plugin

Tags: jquery

I've a custom plugin in jQuery,

```
jQuery.fn.dialog = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // Create dialog
    });
};
```

Now I want to add a function such that it can be called like this:-

```
$("#somediv").dialog.showMe();
```

I tried doing this:-

```
jQuery.fn.dialog.showMe = function() {
    $(this).show();
    // some code
};
```

But I think here `this` is not the div, so `$(this).show()` is not working.

How can I achieve this? Are there any better ways of adding functions to jQuery plugins?

Comment: dialog function has to return an object representing your dialog(s) collection then, you could append any methods to this dialog object's prototype ...

Comment: How can I do that from within `this.each`?

Comment: `dialog.show();` doesn't work.

Comment: a comment: "But I think here this is not the div, so $(this).show() is not working." is the result of the selector your using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded a dialog factory base like what you are looking for ...

Feel free to ask if you have any question.

Test's fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/Zn9ez/)

```
// Dialog box factory base
(function ($) {

    // kind of private vars
    var dialog = function (opt, html) {
        this.domElt = $('<div />', {
            class: 'dialog-container'
        }).append(html);
        return this.init(opt);
    },dialogsStack = [];


    dialog.prototype = {
        init: function (options) {
            dialogsStack.push(this);
            this.params = $.extend(this.params, options, {
                dialogsIndex: (dialogsStack.length - 1)
            });
            console.log(this.params);
        },
        remove: function (all) {
            var dis = this;
            this.domElt.remove();
            if (dialogsStack.length)
                if (all) {
                    $.each(dialogsStack, function (i, el) {
                        el.domElt.remove();
                        // delete el;
                    });
                    dialogsStack = [];
                } else {
                    this.domElt.remove();
                    console.log('rm: ' + this.params.dialogsIndex);
                    dialogsStack.splice(this.params.dialogsIndex, 1);
                }
        },
        showMe: function () {
            this.domElt.appendTo('body');
        }
    };
    $.fn.dialog = function (options) {
        var t = this.eq(0);
        return new dialog(options, $('<div />').append(t).html());
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Another example http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

Comment: Yep nevertheless it looks more like a generic template but seams to be a good summary of [this](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 1):

You should add new method inside dialog:

```
jQuery.fn.dialog = function() {
    this.showMe: function(){
        $(this).show();
    }
};
```

You can call this like:

```
var myDiv = $('#myDiv').dialog();
myDiv.showMe();
```

Or you can extend the current dialog and add method and use in same way above.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the open and close the brace for the function . the function come like this $.fn.extend is Merge the contents of an object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods.

```
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

jquery

```
jQuery.fn.dialog = (function() {
    alert("a");
});

$("#someDiv").dialog();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3Rj/)

Comment: The brace is missing because, I want function to be executed on top of the plugin like $("#somediv").dialog.showMe();, here showMe() is custom function.